# How to configure Nginx WSS running in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, websocket, ws

I have an Nginx pod running in Kubernetes exposed as a node port service.
`default.conf`

```
server{
    listen 80;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://ip:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

**Nginx in server:**
Both ws & wss working(wss working without any ssl certificates)

**Nginx inside a Pod:**
ws is working wss is not working(wss giving handshake errors)

**Expected result:**
Both **ws** & **wss** working with nginx in kubernetes